# Help with NSString of int's to NSString of ASCII characters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, ascii, int

I have implemented some code to convert a NSString of "text" to an NSString of (ASCII) ints, like so:

```
@"Hello" is converted to @"72 101 108 108 111"
```

However, I am having quite a bit of difficulty doing the opposite. Starting with a string of ints (with the spaces) and converting back to the plain string of text.

```
What I need: @"72 101 108 108 111" must be converted to @"Hello"
```

I have tried breaking up the input string into an int array, iterating through it, and using repeatedly the following:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", decCharArray[i]]
```

However, the problem with that is that it parses each particular digit into ASCII, converting the 7, the 2, the space, the 1, etc.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: It seems the problem is converting the string to an array of ints. Can you show that code? Also, what do you try to do? I guess this is not the right thing, unless you're just learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real magic on it. Since you'll be using ASCII, to convert an *int*
to a *char* all you have to do is an assignment, as you may already know:

```
char a = 65; /* a contains 'A' */
```

NSString has a very convenient method `componentsSeparatedByString:` that will
return an array of strings containing your numbers, and you can get an *int*
from a string with the `intValue` method. Thus, all you have to do is to split
the string and iterate through the components assigning their *int* value to a
*char* array. Here is an example function that does that:

```
NSString *
TextFromAsciiCodesString (NSString *string)
{
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSUInteger len = [components count];
    char new_str[len+1];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        new_str[i] = [[components objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

    new_str[i] = '\0';

    return [NSString stringWithCString:new_str
                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

And a simple use of it, with your `"Hello"` example:

```
NSString *string = @"72 101 108 108 111";
NSLog(@"%@", TextFromAsciiCodesString(string));
```

Actually, it's a bit different as your example was `"Hell^K"` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the right approach. Try using `[string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]` to split the string at the spaces. Then you can convert each of those to numbers, and back into strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also trying using `NSString`'s [`enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/enumerateSubstringsInRange%3aoptions%3ausingBlock%3a).

**Usage**

```
NSString * hello = @"72 101 108 108 111";

NSMutableString * result = [NSMutableString string];
[hello enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])
                          options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                       usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                           [result appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [substring intValue]]];
                       }];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```